# how to display rows with same value in php as a group

Tags: php, mysql, sql, grouping

DATABASE Structure:

```
ID | USERID | ENTRYDATE | EXITDATE | PRICE | ROOMID
-----------------------------------------------------
1  | 2      | 2012-10-1 | 2012-10-4| 100   | 1 
2  | 2      | 2012-10-1 | 2012-10-4| 100   | 2 
3  | 2      | 2012-10-1 | 2012-10-4| 100   | 3 
4  | 2      | 2012-10-6 | 2012-10-9| 100   | 4 
5  | 2      | 2012-10-6 | 2012-10-9| 100   | 55
```

i need some help please. I want to display a set of records from this database. i want to display all those with same USERID, but group those with the same ENTRYDATE and EXITDATE in the same DIV. example, the result should be like this...

```
ID | USERID | ENTRYDATE | EXITDATE | PRICE | ROOMID
------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2      | 2012-10-1 | 2012-10-4| 100   | 1
2  | 2      | 2012-10-1 | 2012-10-4| 100   | 2
3  | 2      | 2012-10-1 | 2012-10-4| 100   | 3
```

```
ID | USERID | ENTRYDATE | EXITDATE | PRICE | ROOMID
----------------------------------------------------
4  | 2      | 2012-10-6 | 2012-10-9| 100   | 4
5  | 2      | 2012-10-6 | 2012-10-9| 100   | 5
```

Comment: Take a look at group by in MySQL

Comment: than k you for your suggestions pal.. ill try to visit the link

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly. I assume you have a string-indexed array and you want to split it basing on ENTRYDATE and EXITDATE values. Maybe something like this:

```
$currentEntry = $data[0]['ENTRYDATE'];
$currentExit = $data[0]['EXITDATE'];
$splitted = array();
$i = 0;
foreach ($data as $row) {
  if ($row['ENTRYDATE'] == $currentEntry && $row['ENTRYDATE'] == $currentExit) {
    $splitted[$i] []= $row;
  } else {
    $currentEntry = $row['ENTRYDATE'];
    $currentExit = $row['EXITDATE'];
    $i++;
  }
}
```